# How to learn fitting models?

Tags: r, regression, model-selection

- I am new to R(learned the basics)
- In my current job I have to solve the following problem(the following is an example)

> - Suppose we have 10, 000 users
> - For each user we have his expected monthly spending(in dollars)(with some method that I don't know) for one year
> - What we have to do it fit a model where if for that year we give two dates(Jan-1, March 16), the model should tell us the expected
>     spending(in dollars) for this duration

Question:

> - How to go about and fit a model
> - How to see graphically that model fits correctly with the data points I have
> - How to predict and get answer

Please assist me
Thank you

Comment: It sounds to me like your company already has a model (that you don't understand) and that you want to use that model to make predictions and see how good the predictions are.  I take it you have not just expected spending, but actual spending for some users?  I don't think you'll get a helpful answer until you can describe the model and data in more detail.

Comment: To clarify... if the two dates were Jan-1 and Mar-31, you would have no problem, right, because you just add up the expected spend for Jan, Feb and Mar?  So the problem is, how much of the March estimate is expected to come before 16 March?

Comment: I would say yes

Comment: You could do some sort of weighted average where you assume that a smart estimate for the first half of march is influenced partly by your estimate for all of march and partly by your estimate for february.  But if you have access to the original model there is surely a better way to do this.